# Invalid anonymous type member declarator in LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have two entities. One is "Students" while another is "Subjects".

The details of the two entities is something like:

```
students { id, name}

subjects { studentID, subjectName, passed}
```

where "passed" is of boolean type.

Now I want to query the student name and count of subject that he can pass with follows:

```
var result = from s in db.students 
select new {s.name, s.subjects.Count(i => i.passed.Equals(true)};
```

But i get error msg:Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

I dun know how to solve it. Would anyone help me please?
thanks

Comment: You're missing a closing `)`, but more importantly, you need to *name* the property, as the error message suggest. `Count = s.subjects.dotdotdot...`

Comment: I got it, thanks very much to all.

Answer (score 21):

This means that you need to name your anonymous type's properties that cannot be inferred

```
select new 
{
    s.name, 
    Count=s.subjects.Count(i => i.passed.Equals(true))
};
```

Usually, the property name is good enough, however you are using the Count method, so that property has no inherent name

Answer (score 13):

You have to add anonymous type properties names:

```
var result = from s in db.students 
             select new {
                 s.name,
                 count = s.subjects.Count(i => i.passed.Equals(true)
             };
```

You can skip them only when using member assignment. Compiler will take the name from that member. That's why `s.name` can be applied without specifying property name. `Count()` is an expression, so you have to specify how the property should be named.

Source: [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx)

> If you do not specify member names in the anonymous type, the compiler
>   gives the anonymous type members the same name as the property being
>   used to initialize them. **You must provide a name for a property that
>   is being initialized with an expression** (...)