# Creating a dynamic list of arrays with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have something like this:

```
var test = teamMemberInfoList
    .Select(p => new { 
        p.AssignedTo, 
        p.RemainingCapacity,
        p.RemainingWork, 
        p.RemainingWork- 
        p.RemainingCapacity })
    .ToArray();
```

I would like a list of arrays of strings from values from x numbers of properties. Is there anyway to do this? And the C# line does not work because I cannot do plus or minus either that is also a wish.

Comment: Can you please add an example of output and input to your question. If only you want an Array then you got the answer down there.

Comment: Please show a [mre] showing the structure of the data you're pulling from, an example of the data, and the desired output. I don't understand what is meant by "I cannot do plus or minus either" considering you're talking about an array of strings...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid anonymous type member declarator in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841035/invalid-anonymous-type-member-declarator-in-linq)

Comment: What error do you have? 
[Compiler Error CS0746](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0746). Did you try to google the error message? `c# "Invalid anonymous type member declarator"` ?

Comment: If any gold badge see this. For the dupe target, hammer this one in too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856885/invalid-anonymous-type-member-declarator/18856933

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could use Tuple

test will be an array of Tupe>string>

```
var test = teamMemberInfoList.Select(p => (p.AssignedTo, p.RemainingCapacity,p.RemainingWork, p.RemainingWork - p.RemainingCapacity )).ToArray();
```

or List and test will be an array of List

```
var test = teamMemberInfoList.Select(p => new List<string>(){p.AssignedTo, p.RemainingCapacity,p.RemainingWork, p.RemainingWork - p.RemainingCapacity }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Worked. What do you mean by tuple?

Comment: I will mark your answer in 7 mins.

Comment: (x1,  x2, x3) is a tuple... or you could use Tuple.Create: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-tuple

Comment: Roger, thanks alot. Appreciated!

Comment: What type do you use to pass it to a function?

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you ask? are you speaking about the type of var? if you want string, you have to convert all item to string, if not, the item will be list or tuple of object..and you cast when using

Answer (score 0):

You can *do plus or minus* but you need to provide some name for resulting property (for others compiler will reuse the member access ones):

```
var test = teamMemberInfoList
    .Select(p => new 
    { 
        p.AssignedTo, 
        p.RemainingCapacity,
        p.RemainingWork, 
        Diff = p.RemainingWork- p.RemainingCapacity 
    })
    .ToArray();
```